# Which account Between the mysite App Pool account and the Farm Account to run AppFabric

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, web-application, app-fabric

I am having trouble with getting user profile properly running, and mostly I've been advised that it's because of permissions. So my question is which account should run the AppFabric Caching Service the App Pool Account or the Farm Account.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: which sharepoint version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013/2013 App Fabric Service Run under the Farm Admin account by default.

If you change it then you have to check, you can go Server and open the `service console` and look for the `AppFabricCachingService`. From here you will see under which account it is running.

Comment: I am glad to help you, dont forget to mark it answer if helpful

Comment: How do I do that :)

Comment: just Click the good mark under the up and down vote, click on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Farm account, It will give you warning in Health check issues like: `the farm account should not be used for other services - Distributed Cache Service`

You can use domain user for this service. You can not change user account from Central Admin. You can change the user account using below Powershell code:

```
add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$cacheService = $farm.Services | where {$_.Name -eq “AppFabricCachingService”}
$accnt = Get-SPManagedAccount -Identity <domain\user>
$cacheService.ProcessIdentity.CurrentIdentityType = "SpecificUser"  #provide here domain user
$cacheService.ProcessIdentity.ManagedAccount = $accnt
$cacheService.ProcessIdentity.Update()
$cacheService.ProcessIdentity.Deploy()
```

Wait until it has run, then you will find that the service has a new managed account.
Go back to the Health Analyzer report page and remove the alert.

Reference:

- https://blog.blksthl.com/2012/10/26/how-to-change-the-distributed-cache-service-managed-account/